# How to find npm duplicate packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

`npm dedupe` can flatten the folder structure. However, before doing that. I hope to see a list of duplicate packages, so that I know whether or not to go forward. Is there such a feature? If not, is there some sort of scripts that help me achieve this?

Comment: Yea. Let me fix the typo.

Comment: There's no apparent feature like that, unless it's hidden somewhere.

Comment: sad. then hope someone have a grep script or something like that.

Comment: @李允智  汗. lol. Yes. Not specific to one package though. I'm trying to find out all the dup packages.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
 npm ls --parseable | xargs -L1 sh -c 'basename $1' dummy | sort | uniq -c | grep -v "^ *1 " | sort -rn
```

The pipeline here is:

1. List packages in parsable format
2. Strip each path down to only the package name
3. Sort package names alphabetically to prepare for counting unique names
4. Group and count unique package names
5. Hide packages which are not duplicated (count = 1)
6. Sort again by descending number of occurrences

Comment: this is awesome. Do you mean xargs -L 1? "-l" returns an error.

Comment: yes -L1 is more compatible, though -l is also supported on my test system (Ubuntu 12.04), I've edited the answer.

Comment: To include versions, you can use `npm ls --parseable --long | cut -d':' -f2 | sort | uniq -c` to see how many times each version of a package is depended on. Can be useful for finding where you are using both v1.0.0 and v2.0.0 of a package (because different packages depend on different versions).

Comment: This answer does not properly handle namespaced packages, like `@babel/core`. Instead, I am using the following: `npm ls | grep -v " deduped" | grep -oe "\S*@" | sed 's/.$//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`

Answer (score 5):

Try [find-duplicate-dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-duplicate-dependencies). As well as versions it shows you the simplified path to the duplicates:

```
$ find-duplicate-dependencies
This package has the following duplicate dependencies:

regenerator-runtime :
[ { name: 'regenerator-runtime',
    version: '0.11.1',
    from: undefined,
    path: 'project/react-select/emotion/babel-plugin-emotion/babel-core/babel-runtime' },
  { name: 'regenerator-runtime',
    version: '0.12.1',
    from: undefined,
    path: 'project/recompose/@babel/runtime' } ]
```